# Issue replacing fullstop - breaks images too

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

We are looking to change all the fullstop colours on the site to be green. We are trying to wrap all fullstops in a span, this works however it breaks images and removes breaks from the HTML. The code is:-

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col txt-col aos-init aos-animate" data-aos="fade-right">
            <h2 class="">Test<br> Test. <br> Test</h2>
            <h4>Test content.</h4>
            <p>Testing 1 2 3.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col image-col aos-init aos-animate" data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-delay="250">
            <p><img src="fake/path.png"/></p>
        </div>
    </div>          
</div>

<script>
$('p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6').each(function () {
     $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/\./g, '<span class="fs-color">.</span> '));
}); 
</script>
```

Could you please advise?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter over the contents of the element to get only the text nodes, then replace their text if necessary.

```js
$('p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6').each(function () {
  $(this).contents().filter((_, el) => el.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE).each(function(){
    $(this).replaceWith($(this).text().replace(/\./g, '<span class="fs-color">.</span> '));
  });
});
```

```css
.fs-color{color:blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col txt-col aos-init aos-animate" data-aos="fade-right">
            <h2 class="">Test<br> Test. <br> Test</h2>
            <h4>Test content.</h4>
            <p>Testing 1 2 3.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col image-col aos-init aos-animate" data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-delay="250">
            <p><img src="fake/path.png"/></p>
        </div>
    </div>          
</div>
```